# LINQ query with sub-query list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

The query below should be selecting a list of information from different tables, and should also bring back a list of `VehicleName`s that are related to each `ID` coming back from `db.Reservations`

The query brings back data, but the list of VehicleNames only has one record, and it should bring back anywhere up to 5 records, depending on how many vehicles were reserved for that specific instance. I have tried adding a foreach to the `VehicleName` line in the `select` but I don't think I am using it right. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can retrieve the list of values I need?

```
 var query = from r in db.Reservations
             let e = db.Employees.Where(x => r.RequestorID == x.ColleagueID).FirstOrDefault() 
             let rtv = db.ReservationToVehicle.Where(x => r.ID == x.ReservationID).FirstOrDefault()
             let rs = db.ReservationStatus.Where(x => r.ID == x.ReservationID).FirstOrDefault()
             let rst = db.ReservationStatusTypes.Where(x => rs.ReservationStatusTypeID == x.ID).FirstOrDefault()
             select new
             {
                 StartDate = r.StartDate,
                 EndDate = r.EndDate,
                 Destination = r.Destination,
                 PurposeOfTrip = r.PurposeOfTrip,
                 TransportingStudents = r.TransportStudentsFG,
                 EmployeeName = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName,                            
                 ApprovalStatus = rst.StatusType,
                 ThemeColor = r.ThemeColor,
                 VehicleName = (from v in db.Vehicles
                                where v.ID == rtv.VehicleID
                                select v.VehicleName).ToList()
              };
```

EDIT: Updated query, still uncertain how to get back list of Vehicles that have been reserved

```
var query = from r in db.Reservations
            let e = db.Employees.Where(x => r.RequestorID == x.ColleagueID).FirstOrDefault()
            let rtv = db.ReservationToVehicle.Where(x => r.ID == x.ReservationID).Select(y => y.VehicleID).ToList()
            let rs = db.ReservationStatus.Where(x => r.ID == x.ReservationID).FirstOrDefault()
            let rst = db.ReservationStatusTypes.Where(x => rs.ReservationStatusTypeID == x.ID).FirstOrDefault()
            select new
            {
                StartDate = r.StartDate,
                EndDate = r.EndDate,
                Destination = r.Destination,
                PurposeOfTrip = r.PurposeOfTrip,
                TransportingStudents = r.TransportStudentsFG,
                EmployeeName = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName,
                ApprovalStatus = rst.StatusType,
                ThemeColor = r.ThemeColor,
                VehicleName = (from v in db.Vehicles
                              where v.ID == rtv.VehicleID
                              select v.VehicleName).ToList()
            };
```

`rtv.VehicleID` does not exist anymore, now `rtv` comes back with a list of IDs....I need to be able to get into that list to find where `v.ID` is `IN` the `rtv` list

Comment: You have `rtv` defined with `FirstOrDefault` which means only one rtv. Is `VehicleID` a type of vehicle or the id for a single particular vehicle? You are defining `VehicleName` from the single `rtv`.

Comment: I updated the query, but still am not sure how to get that list back. Can you look and see if I'm on the right track? I feel like I'm close, but missing something really small. @NetMage

Comment: `where rtv.Contains(v.ID)` but I would take off the `.ToList()` from `rtv`'s definition.

Comment: OMG this is what I have been spending my whole day on and it's finally resolved, I can't thank you enough! Side note: I've been pretty sick and I may not be able to comprehend things fully right now...I'm sure this issue was not as hard as I made it out to be. hah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like people already told you this in the comments, but here's the code that ought to work:

```
var query = from r in db.Reservations
            let e = db.Employees.Where(x => r.RequestorID == x.ColleagueID).FirstOrDefault()
            let rtv = db.ReservationToVehicle.Where(x => r.ID == x.ReservationID).Select(y => y.VehicleID)
            let rs = db.ReservationStatus.Where(x => r.ID == x.ReservationID).FirstOrDefault()
            let rst = db.ReservationStatusTypes.Where(x => rs.ReservationStatusTypeID == x.ID).FirstOrDefault()
            select new
            {
                StartDate = r.StartDate,
                EndDate = r.EndDate,
                Destination = r.Destination,
                PurposeOfTrip = r.PurposeOfTrip,
                TransportingStudents = r.TransportStudentsFG,
                EmployeeName = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName,
                ApprovalStatus = rst.StatusType,
                ThemeColor = r.ThemeColor,
                VehicleName = (from v in db.Vehicles
                              where rtv.Contains(v.ID)
                              select v.VehicleName).ToList()
            };
```

I'd also recommend looking at [setting up navigation properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships) between your entities. Your query could be much simpler, something like this:

```
var query = from r in db.Reservations
            let e = r.Requestor
            let rs = r.ReservationStatus
            let rst = rs.ReservationStatusType
            select new
            {
                StartDate = r.StartDate,
                EndDate = r.EndDate,
                Destination = r.Destination,
                PurposeOfTrip = r.PurposeOfTrip,
                TransportingStudents = r.TransportStudentsFG,
                EmployeeName = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName,
                ApprovalStatus = rst.StatusType,
                ThemeColor = r.ThemeColor,
                VehicleName = r.Vehicles.Select(v => v.VehicleName).ToList()
            };
```

Comment: Ok cool, thank you for the info! MVC and EF are newer to me and I've just been jumping in to get things moving along. That is a very helpful link. :)